# List values with MaxDate

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

Im trying to create ie query to show itens with MAX DATE, but I don´t know how !
Follow the script and result:

```
Select
    results.severity As "Count_severity",
    tasks.name As task,
    results.host,
    to_timestamp(results.date)::date
From
    tasks Inner Join
    results On results.task = tasks.id
Where
    tasks.name Like '%CORP 0%' And
    results.severity >= 7 And
    results.qod > 70
```

I need to show only tasks with the last date of each one.
Can you help me ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps Postgresql, or is it really Oracle?)

Comment: Im using Postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using Postgres (as suggested by the use of casting operator `::`). If so - and I follow you correctly - you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on(t.name) 
    r.severity, t.name as task, r.host, to_timestamp(r.date::bigint)::date
from tasks t
inner join results r on r.task = t.id
where t.name like '%corp 0%' and r.severity >= 7 and r.qod > 70 
order by t.name, to_timestamp(r.date::bigint)::date desc
```

This guarantees one row per task only; which row is picked is controlled by the `order by` clause, so the above gets the row with the greatest `date` (time portion left apart). If there are ties, it is undefined which row is returned. You might want to adapt the `order by` clause to your exact requirement, if it is different than what I understood.

---

On the other hand, if you want top ties, then use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select r.severity, t.name as task, r.host, to_timestamp(r.date::bigint)::date,
        rank() over(partition by t.name order by to_timestamp(r.date::bigint)::date desc) rn
    from tasks t
    inner join results r on r.task = t.id
    where t.name like '%corp 0%' and r.severity >= 7 and r.qod > 70 
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Im using PostgreSQL , but I need something different , Im adding a new image to explain better ... I need list , only the itens with last date of each category (task name)

Comment: I fixed to  to_timestamp(r.date)::date , but I receiver null result of my query

Comment: @luizespinola: I adapted the queries to handle the unix timestamps.